# zsh accepts syntactically incorrect loop construct

Tags: zsh

By mistake, I typed something like this:

```
 for f in a b; echo a; echo x
```

The output produced was

```
a
a
x
```

as if I had written

```
for f in a b; do echo a; done; echo x
```

Could someone explain, why my code produced this example? Checking the man page, it clearly says that the required syntax has to be

> for name ... [ in word ... ] term do list done

No shortcut explains that I could leave out the `do` or `done`.

I'm running zsh 5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, that syntax is not described in the section that introduces the `for` loop. Instead it's listed with some other short command versions, in a separate part of the `zshmisc` man page titled *ALTERNATE FORMS FOR COMPLEX COMMANDS*.

> for name ... [ in word ... ] term sublist
> where  term is at least one newline or ;.  Another short form of for.

The introduction to the section mentions some caveats:

> Many of  zsh's  complex  commands  have  alternate  forms.   These
> are non-standard  and  are  likely not to be obvious even to seasoned
> shell programmers; they should not be used anywhere that portability
> of shell code is a concern.
>
> The short versions below only work if sublist is of the form `{ list
> }' or if the SHORT_LOOPS option is set.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is so bizarre that I may like it. BTW, if I ever jump out of a window in frenzy, it is because I try to get some desparately needed information from the zsh man page. It contains everything we need, but constantly in parts we don't look at.